# Div resizing to fit content but then disabling auto size.

Tags: jquery, css

Sorry for the title there, unsure how to accurately describe it in a line!

I have some dynamic content loading to divs and then I have a smooth resizing function that animates the height of said div to auto.

```
function smoothSize(div) {

var $selector = $('#' + div);   
$selector.data('oHeight',$selector.height()).css('height','auto').data('nHeight',$selector.height()).height($selector.data('oHeight')).animate({height: $selector.data('nHeight')},400);

}
```

This works fine in one orientation or viewport size, but as soon as you change the orientation to landscape or resize the window in desktop, the divs remain at their current height so the content overflows the div if you shrink the window (or the opposite happens and there's lots of extra space in the div if you stretch it).

If I disable the function, then the divs automatically snap to the size of whatever content I put in them, which is fine, but then I lose the nice effect.

Am I right in thinking that the function is not setting the height back to auto, or does it need to set the height to zero after animating?

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
function smoothSize(div) {
    var $selector = $('#' + div);   
    $selector.data('oHeight',$selector.height()).css('height','auto').data('nHeight',$selector.height()).css('min-height', $selector.data('oHeight')).animate({max-height: $selector.data('nHeight')},400);
}
```

if this didn't work, then please manage to provide a JSFiddle.